# Can't build the swingx-all jar with maven

Tags: java, eclipse, maven, build, swingx

I'm using eclipse with the m2eclipse to `Check out Maven Projects from SCM` from https://svn.java.net/svn/swingx~svn/trunk.

This works perfectly; if I use `Run as...`-->`Maven build...` on the `swingx-project` eclipse project, all the dependend Maven-projects build their jars into the `target`-directories: `swingx-action-1.6.5-1.jar`, `swingx-core-1.6.5-1.jar`"and so on. They are working with my application, all sources and resources packed right. 
But the `swingx-all-1.6.5-1.jar` which should aggregate the content of some jars has only 3 KiloByte, because no sources were found. The console output is:

```
....
[INFO] --- maven-resources-plugin:2.6:resources (default-resources) @ swingx-all ---
[INFO] Using 'UTF-8' encoding to copy filtered resources.
[INFO] Copying 0 resource
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- maven-compiler-plugin:3.0:compile (default-compile) @ swingx-all ---
[INFO] No sources to compile
[INFO] 
....
```

The swingx-all `pom.xml` can be seen at https://java.net/projects/swingx/sources/svn/content/trunk/swingx-all/pom.xml?rev=4316

Why is this `pom.xml` not finding the required sourcecode and resources?

Answer (score 2):

There is no *src/main/java* in that module as it is meant to use sources from all other modules.

Without any profile specified, nothing is made to gather these other modules sources, so add *-Pjvnet-release* to your command to trigger that.